# 'No launch handler registered for task with identifier ...' (Swift)

Tags: swift, background, task

I have this code that is a text-to-speech and that at the end it opens the default browser with a specified link

```
func speak(text : String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil, link: String) {
        let state = returnState()
        print(state)
        if state == .quiet {
            do {

                self.state = .speaking
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default)
                try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
                let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
                utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: language)
                synthesizer.speak(utterance)
                self.showWaveform()
                self.callbackSpeak = callback
                let url = URL(string: link)!
                let seconds = 4.0
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                }

            } catch {
                print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

`'No launch handler registered for task with identifier com.maps.fetch.activities'`

I checked the permissions and under "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers", I do have "com.maps.fetch.activities".

[image]

I think I have to register a task with that identifier, but I am not really sure what that is and where should I do it. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you didn't call `BGTaskScheduler.shared.register` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
if ( !BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: BackupTask.identifier,
                    using: nil) { task in
    BackupTask.handleProcess(task as? BGProcessingTask)
} ){
    logHelper.w("BackupTask register failed.")
}
```

And put this into `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    BackupTask.scheduleProcessing()
}
```

This is what `scheduleProcessing` looks like.

```
@available(iOS 13, *)
static func scheduleProcessing() {
    let logHelper = LogHelper(subsystem: "TimeMachineTask", category: "scheduleProcessing")

    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: TimeMachineTask.identifier)
    // Fetch no earlier than 5 minutes from now
    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:  60 * 15)
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        logHelper.i("Submit new request.")
    } catch {
        logHelper.e("Could not schedule app refresh: %@", error: error)
    }
}
```

`BGTaskScheduler.shared.register` is telling iOS what to do after launching your background task which is the "launch handler" you're missing.
`BackupTask.scheduleProcessing` is where it actually schedule a job.

You can download their sample project to see how it works with `OperationQueue`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks